# Достал из кармана «магнум»

Tags: кавычки

Будьте добры, подскажите: достал из кармана «магнум» (имеется в виду пистолет) — нужны ли кавычки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Магнум** (оружие) — оружие и патрон повышенной мощности под данный тип оружия.

https://zen.yandex.ru/media/wt1/chto-takoe-magnum-5bca4d3a9a61e000aa8e6688

В специализированной литературе это название может писаться различным образом, но в литературе художественной слово заключают в кавычки — "магнум". Это связано с тем, что оно **не настолько широко известно**, чтобы использоваться без кавычек.

Для сравнения: более популярный ***кольт*** чаще пишется без кавычек, хотя написание в кавычках тоже встречается.

Примеры:

Но и этого мгновения хватило, чтобы Юукси ловко выхватила из сумочки вороненый **«магнум»** и нацелила в сторону пришельца. [Иван Охлобыстин. Танго смерти // «Столица», 1997.05.27]

Вынул из кобуры новенький, словно игрушечный, **«магнум»**, кобуру бросил в лежавший на полу ящик и снова вставил его в стол. [Анатолий Мельник. Авторитет (2000)]

Четвертый схватил свой **«магнум»** и направил его на Савелия. [Виктор Доценко. Тридцатого уничтожить! (2000)]

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Добавлю что-нибудь из правил, а то ответ никому не нравится

ПАС http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=92#pp92

**§ 200.** Названия производственных **марок технических изделий** (машин, приборов и т. п.) заключаются в кавычки и пишутся с прописной буквы, напр.: автомобили «Москвич-412»,  стиральная машина «Эврика», холодильники «Бирюса», «Минск», видеомагнитофон «Панасоник».

Однако названия **самих этих изделий** (кроме названий, совпадающих с собственными именами — личными и географическими) пишутся в кавычках со строчной буквы, напр.: **«москвич», «тойота», «вольво» (автомобили), «боинг», «фантом» (самолеты), «панасоник» (магнитофон);** но: «Волга», «Ока», «Таврия» (автомобили), «Руслан» (самолет), «Минск» (холодильник); **исключения: «жигули», «мерседес» (автомобили).**

Примечание 2. В бытовом употреблении названия средств передвижения могут употребляться **и без кавычек,** напр.: приехал на стареньком москвиче, на роскошном кадиллаке.

Итак, названия могут быть именами **собственными** и писаться с прописной буквы, а могут быть **нарицательными** (написание со строчной буквы, с кавычками или без кавычек). Употребление **кавычек** для нарицательных существительных зависит от того, насколько они **общеупотребительны**, а также от стиля речи.